# How Can I Use The Error Color for `guibg` and `ctermbg`

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, whitespace

I have the following Vim code which highlights trailing whitespace in red:

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

But instead of making the color "red", I want to use the color scheme's default error color. I tried using "error" instead of "red", but that didn't work and it gave me an error saying that the color is not recognized.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way is to link `ExtraWhitespace` to `Error` with

```
colorscheme whatever
hi link ExtraWhitespace Error
```

Or if you use `:h colorscheme-override`:

```
augroup my_colorschemes
  au!
  au Colorscheme pablo hi link ExtraWhitespace Error
augroup END
colorscheme pablo
```

In recent vim you can also use combination of `hlget()`/`hlset()` functions to target specific colors in highlighting:

```
let hl_err = hlget('Error')[0]
call hlset([{"name": "ExtraWhitespace", "ctermbg": hl_err.ctermbg, "guibg": hl_err.guibg}])
```

Comment: The first solution worked for me but I would like to inverse the foreground and background colors. Is this possible? As for the third solution, it told me that the `hlget` function doesn't exist, I am on Neovim version 0.7.2.

Comment: @Amarakon, I don't know if neovim has similar functions, you can check its help, I guess.

Comment: `hlget()` was added to Vim fairly recently @Amarakon (Nov last year); there's [a PR to port it to Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/16270), but it hasn't seen activity for a while.

Comment: Is there a way to use `highlight link ExtraWhiteSpace Error` and then invert `ExtraWhiteSpace` foreground and background colors without using `hlget()`?

Comment: @Amarakon I don't think so. But you can pick up colors Error uses and use them directly.

Comment: How can I use this method to set the background color of `Error` to the foreground color of `ExtraWhiteSpace`?